# Level scheduling of triangular sparse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, parallel-computing, sparse-matrix

Assume one has a triangular sparse matrix and want to solve $Lx=b$ where $b$ and $L$ are known. This can be done easily by using forward substitution when $L$ is a lower triangular matrix. Forward substitution is highly sequential and hard to implement in parallel.
I have read some articles about level scheduling where $L$ is reordered so that different levels appear which can be solved in parallel. A good reference seems to be the book of Saad where also the forward substitution with level scheduling is explained.

But I do not really get how the level scheduling is performed and the vector $q$ is filled. Could someone please provide an example or something?

Comment: Even if parallelized, the problem as stated is intrinsically BLAS2 and your opportunities for speedup might be limited (you're probably already memory-bound, adding more processors won't change this). That said, solving by multiple right hand sides is BLAS3, and does require some thought/strategy to parallelize, so I do think the question is worth asking and answering.

Comment: Memory bound code still needs to be parallel to realize full system bandwidth.

Comment: On many contemporary x86_64 desktop systems, one or two (of 8 or even 16) cores can easily saturate the memory bandwidth.  There's not a lot of benefit to parallelizing operations like matrix-vector multiplication on such systems.

Comment: "the book of Saad" is a particularly bad reference/citation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to discover parallelism in L and U, but a better approach is to reorder the original matrix. Luby & Jones/Plassman describe this scheme: you can generate a multi-colouring in parallel, and then in the solution every colour has all processors concurrently active.

Comment: Explicit reordering of the original matrix may have other drawbacks, e.g. multi-colouring generally goes against the fill-in minimization in the (incomplete) LU factorization. Depending on the problem, multi-colouring may be actually less efficient than level-scheduling, so I think it's worth answering the original question.

Comment: Actually, explicit re-ordering is what's happening in all classical LU algorithms. Finding levels is more or less multi-frontal. Complete minimization is probably NP complete, but minimum degree does a reasonable job. And then of course one uses a multi-frontal version of that, which gives you parallelism.